# Client Time in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, time

PHP, as far as I know, can only find the time on server-side. I want the time to be in client time. My approach was to use Javascript, get the client's time, pass it to PHP. This works, but I need to store this "time" in a `log` file. Here is my code so far:

**JS**

```
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("timestamp").value = d.getTime() / 1000;
```

**PHP**

```
$datevar = date('d/m/Y', $_POST['timestamp']) . ' at ' . date('h:i', $_POST['timestamp']) . PHP_EOL;

$log_file_name = '1.log'; 
file_put_contents($log_file_name, $variable .":  $variable,  $variable, $datevar"  , FILE_APPEND);
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="survey.php">
<input type="hidden" id="timestamp" name="timestamp" value="" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

With the above code, the log file just shows exactly the JS code, not the actual time.

I would like to store the actual client time. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `$_POST['timestamp']` actually look like when you get it in your PHP?

Comment: Do you wait to run the script code until after the document exists?

Comment: Set the `timestamp` value just before the form submit. You might set the time when page is load (i mean script load)

Comment: Have both sides work off UNIX timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the javascript code:

```
Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
```

To get the unix timestamp on the client side and then send it in to your form to be stored in the logged file. You can then use PHP's

```
strftime("%b, %d, %Y", TIMESTAMP)
```

Method to convert the submitted unix timestamp submitted from the client's end

Comment: Thanks I'll try this!

Comment: Nope, sorry nothing came up in the log file. I set `$datevar` to `strftime("%b, %d, %Y", TIMESTAMP)` and put `Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);` in my JS and left the hidden input.